# wordpress after migrate cannot find pages

Tags: wordpress, migration

I try to migrate my wordpress to new domain.(wordpres version 4.9.7)
The index.page is working, but other pages defined in wp_posts table not working properly.

like:

```
https://mysite.amazonaws.com/?page_id=622
```

I got 404 not find error.

I use apache2 with configuration:

```
<Directory /home/admin/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The .htaccess file is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

the page editor part do not present the review page properly.

Anyone know where is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: once you can remove the .htaccess file and again refresh site url. check it

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your Permalinks from `wp-admin`?

Comment: I remove .htaccess it still have same error

Comment: As @HamzaAhmad said, refresh your permalink. Go to backend permalink page, change nothing, and hit save.

Answer (score 0):

find the wp_options table, edit siteurl and home entries with the new url.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in following order

1. Set the permalink to default(Plain ?p=ID) from wp-admin login page (http(s)://site.name/wp-admin/options-permalink.php)
2. If this works, then set the permalink to your desired format and try again.
3. Try disabling plugins.
4. If you domain is changed then you have to update the new website name in wp_options table. Refer to https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Actually my not found page is:https://*******.amazonaws.com/homepage/ which is permalink redirect correctly. but still have error

Answer (score 0):

Refresh permalink fist after that.

Go to the WordPress backend where you have all pages and data from there you go inside "tool menu " and import all page and content.

After that

Go to another website where you want to migration

and export file which you import from the first WordPress backend

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1st methord:
Go to file manager and you can remove the `.htaccess` file and again refresh the site URL.

2nd method:
Go to settings->permalinks and click the Save button to rewrite flush. And then hard reload the browser. It'll work hopefully.

3rd method:
Go to settings->permalinks edit your permalinks settings as "Custom Structure"
and edit like this `/index.php/%postname%/`